# Creating multiple files using script shell

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create several files using a shell script. So far I have this and works.

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="VALUE 1"
var2="VALUE 2"
ext="cfg"

cat > file1 << EOF1
do some commands on "$var1" 
and/or "$var2"
EOF1
```

Now I have to create 50 files and the 50 files will have the same text just a few changes and I'm planning to use variables for the changes.

My question is how do I create the 50 files (each file needs to have a specific name but all have the same extension. (.cfg)

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would loop either over a counter:

```
for index in $(seq 50)
do
    touch "$index"
done
```

or over a given list of names:

```
names=(first second third [...])
for name in "${names[@]}"
do
    touch "$name"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What determines the file name you will be creating?  Is it something you can loop through?  Call from an argument to the script?

You can replace file1 with a variable

```
outfile=file1

cat > $outfile << EOF1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..5}
do
  touch "$i.txt"
done
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. I noticed you answered a questions which is almost 4 years old with an answer that is already given in another answer. If you think your solution has some benefit, can you explain what advantages it has over the existing solution? In general, it is encouraged to not only post code as an answer but rather explain it.